# as3 - Changing position checking for in IF statement

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to catch X.Y positions with an IF statement, and IF the coordinates are true I want it to go on to the next set of coordinates. In the code below I attempted my best but I keep getting the "Cannot assign to a non-reference value." Error.

```
public function onDd(event:TimerEvent):void  
    { 
        if (this.rootClass.world.strMapName == "test" && a1.x = a1.x = 327.1 && a1.y = 249.65)
            {
                a1.x = 360.7; 
                a1.y = 204.25;
            }
        else if (a1.x = 410.15 && a1.y = 204.25)
            {
                a1.x = 360.7; 
                a1.y = 204.25;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Your if statements should use `==` or `===` equality operators not the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: @Marty Yup that what was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a wrong comparison operator

If you want to compare two values you must use `==` or `===`

So your code will become:

```
public function onDd(event:TimerEvent):void { 
    if (this.rootClass.world.strMapName == "test" && a1.x == 327.1 && a1.y == 249.65) {
            a1.x = 360.7; 
            a1.y = 204.25;
        }
    else if (a1.x == 410.15 && a1.y == 204.25) {
            a1.x = 360.7; 
            a1.y = 204.25;
        }
}
```